# How many electoral votes were voting more Republican than the national average in 2020 as of data right now?

Tags: united-states, electoral-college

Biden is leading in the popular vote by 3.8 percentage points. I am wondering about this topic of states that lean one way relative to the nation. It appears that this is helpful because it shows Electoral College advantage and bias. A preliminary analysis shows NH and MN both losing that status.

I asked an [earlier question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/56532/did-2016-set-a-record-for-the-number-of-electoral-votes-in-jurisdictions-voting) about 2016 about if 320 electoral votes (that was 2016's total) this set a record. And while it set a modern record, this record was broken in 1968 and was also roughly equaled in 1940.

Comment: I don't understand the title question, what do you mean, electoral votes?

Comment: I mean the total number of electoral votes in all states fitting that description. For example, Texas would count as one for this example, and that # would be *38* in that case.

Comment: So you want the sum of all states and CDs that have more republican votes or pct than trump's national vote pct?

Comment: The sum of EVs in all states with percentage in two-party vote for Trump exceeding national %. The congressional district *only* applies to Maine and Nebraska because they have split electoral votes, and 2 are like normal.

Comment: So all of the states he won (this is not 1992; anything he won he has more than the about 48% he has nationally) plus any state he lost but it was really close (like AZ and GA)? My question for the OP is what is the relevance of that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thirty-three EV areas voted more Republican than Trump's two-vote share (48.0%), totaling 311 EVs. Data from [Cook Political](https://cookpolitical.com/2020-national-popular-vote-tracker) (undated, but downloaded 11/20). Twenty-eight went for Trump overall, but six were called for Biden (PA, GA, MI, AZ, WI, NV). No areas voted less Republican than Trump's two-vote share, but were called for him, so I'm not really sure what the utility of this measure is.

Those jurisdictions, in size order:

- 38 EVs: TX
- 29 EVs: FL
- 20 EVs: PA
- 18 EVs: OH
- 16 EVs: GA, MI
- 15 EVs: NC
- 11 EVs: TN, IN, AZ
- 10 EVs: MO, WI
- 9 EVs: AL, SC
- 8 EVs: KY, LA
- 7 EVs: OK
- 6 EVs: AR, UT, MS, KS, IA, NV
- 5 EVs: WV
- 4 EVs: ID
- 3 EVs: WY, ND, SD, MT, AK,
- 2 EVs: NE at-large*
- 1 EVs: NE1*, ME2

* - Nebraska and Maine's two Senator-equivalent EVs are awarded to the statewide winner, this means the votes in NE1 are counted in both NE1 and NE at-large. In other words, the state-wide margin was higher than Trump's average in NE at-large and NE1, but not NE2 (which Biden won).

---

Code :

```
library(tidyverse)

vote <- read_csv("cook.csv") %>%
  select(stateid, EV, called, ends_with("_votes")) %>%
  mutate(
    two_party_vote = dem_votes + rep_votes,
    gop_pct = rep_votes / two_party_vote
  )

US <- vote[1, ]

GOP_gt_avg <- vote[-1, ] %>%
  filter(
    gop_pct > US$gop_pct
  ) %>%
  arrange(desc(EV), desc(gop_pct))

table(GOP_gt_avg$called)
```